# What is this Invalid regular expression flag error?

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm conditionally rendering a div in my React app. This...

```
    if (props.trades.length > 0)
    return <div class="header">Your trades:</div>
    else
    return <div class="header">You haven't made any trades.</div>
```

works but I want to include a link in the second option like so

```
    if (props.trades.length > 0)
    return <div class="header">Your trades:</div>
    else
    return <div class="header">You haven't made any trades. Click <a to={{/page}}>here</a> to make a trade.</div>
```

But I'm getting this error: "Parsing error: Invalid regular expression flag" at the closing a tag.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you should use the `to` this way:

Notice: if you are using the html `a tag`, you would probably want to change `to` to `href`

```
<a to="/page">here</a>
// or 
const to = "/page"
...
<a to={to}>here</a>
```

Comment: Doh. Got it. Thanks.